# AngularJS compartir en Facebook

Tags: angularjs, facebook

¿Cómo compartir una url o artículo en Facebook de un sitio ruteado con AngularJS?

Sucede que Facebook no reconoce las meta tags og: ....
He buscado mucho pero no encuentro respuestas concretas.
¿Alguna idea?

He intentado lo siguiente:
En mi código HTML declaro mis meta tags open graph como variables de enlace, por ejemplo:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ post.title }}" />
```

Esto funciona bien para HTML, cuando inspecciono el código en mi navegador, la propiedad `content` muestra el valor de `post.title`

El problema está en que Facebook no hace lo propio. Cuando ingreso a la consola de depuración de Facebook, la vista previa del artículo compartido se muestra con el título "{{ post.title }}"

Comment: No has intentado usar Angular Socialshare?

Comment: Si @AlbertoRojas pero no funciona para compartir una pagina enrutada. Los meta og:tags de facebook deben estar incluidos en el código html y no pueden ser variables interpoladas por angular.

Comment: estas intentandolo desde el localhost?

Comment: Debería funcionar a no ser claro que utilices directivas en la propia definición de la meta tag.

Comment: Intentó [depurar](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) los posibles errores en facebook. ? y la vez visualizar como se verá su contenido compartido?

Comment: puede que estés buscando esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533846/single-page-application-with-angularjs-and-facebook-share-button

Comment: @MarceloForclaz te sugiero modifiques tu pregunta, revisa nuevamente [ask] para que sea bien recibida, actualmente puede ser candidata a cierre, saludos!

Comment: Prueba [content]="post.title".

Comment: ¿Lograste hacerlo funcionar?

Comment: Sí, lo que hice fue un script PHP que renderice las etiquetas meta:og de facebook desde el lado del servidor y redirija a la página que deseo compartir. Ni bien pueda publico el código.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que podrías registrar el botón Compartir presionar controlador de eventos en "Forma angular". Mueva la lógica al controlador y use la directiva ng-click para activar la acción de compartir.

Mi implementación

HTML

```html
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'YOUR APP ID', status: true, cookie: true,
        xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="fbCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <div>{{post.title}}</div>
        <div>{{post.content}}</div>
        <button ng-click="share(post)">SHARE</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Controller

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller("fbCtrl",function($scope){
  $scope.posts = [{id:1,title:"title1",content:"content1",caption:"caption1"},{id:2,title:"title2",content:"content2",caption:"caption2"}];
  $scope.share = function(post){
    FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        name: 'This is the content of the "name" field.',
        link: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/external-xfbml/'+post.id,
        picture: 'http://www.hyperarts.com/external-xfbml/share-image.gif',
        caption: post.caption,
        description: 'This is the content of the "description" field, below the caption.',
        message: ''
    });
  }
});
```

Screenshot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El autor de la respuesta es : @Chickenrice

[La pregunta original donde esta la respuesta es esta.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533846/single-page-application-with-angularjs-and-facebook-share-button)